# Who is the speaker in Psalms 82:6?

Tags: psalms

I believe Asaf is speaking in Psalm 82:1 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Psalm+82/)):

> <sub>A Psalm of Asaph.</sub>
>
> ```
> God has taken his place in the divine council;
>     in the midst of the gods he holds judgment:
> ```

Then God is speaking in Psalm 82:2-4:

> ```
> How long will you judge unjustly
>     and show partiality to the wicked? Selah
> Give justice to the weak and the fatherless;
>     maintain the right of the afflicted and the destitute.
> Rescue the weak and the needy;
>     deliver them from the hand of the wicked.
> ```

I believe Asaf or God could be speaking in Psalm 82:5:

> ```
> They have neither knowledge nor understanding,
>     they walk about in darkness;
>     all the foundations of the earth are shaken.
> ```

It's hard to say. But, who is speaking in Ps. 82:6 (I said, "You are gods.")?

> ```
> I said, You are gods,
>     sons of the Most High, all of you;
> nevertheless, like men you shall die,
>     and fall like any prince.
> ```

(Quotation punctuation, which was added by the translator and did not exist in Biblical Hebrew, has been removed.)

**Is there some way to determine who is calling people "gods"?**

---

Clearly it's Asaf speaking in the final verse:

> ```
> Arise, O God, judge the earth;
>     for you shall inherit all the nations!
> ```

Comment: I just made a pretty radical [edit] to fill in the context and expand on what the hermeneutic issue was being asked about.  If I messed anything up, feel free to either edit further or (if I really botched things) rollback.

Comment: All seems fine to me! Thank you for giving me your thoughts.

Comment: Jon's question on the same passage: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/who-are-the-divine-beings-in-psalm-82

Comment: I just realized this question exists. Don't have time to answer at the moment, though. Read [the NET Bible footnotes](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Psalms+82) on this psalm for some great info. There are good odds this was a Ugaritic psalm that was co-opted by the Hebrews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Not getting much of a response, so I examined the scriptures closer.

In v. 1, Asaf writes that God is standing in the congregation of God and judging among the "gods"/ judges. The usage of the 3rd person indicates Asaf's own thought.

However, in v. 2, the person speaking asks a question, "How long will you judge...and accept…?" The Hebrew words translated as "judge" and "accept" — תִּשְׁפְּטוּ and תִּשְׂאוּ — are conjugated in the 2nd person, plural number. Thus, the individual speaking is speaking to a group of people. The change in person and number, from 3rd person singular ("God is standing") to 2nd person plural ("you (pl.) judge….you (pl.) accept"), indicates a change in the speaker. Asaf, the author of the entire 82nd psalm, is now writing the words of God who is speaking and judging among the "gods"/ judges. The reader may thus understand it as though God Himself is speaking. This same perspective occurs in vv. 3-4.

In v. 5, the verbs change from 2nd person plural (in vv. 2-4) to 3rd person plural (יָדְעוּ, יָבִינוּ,יִתְהַלָּכוּ ). This indicates that Asaf himself is speaking again and recording his own thoughts/ words about the "gods"/ judges.

In v. 6, the verb changes to 1st person singular, אֲנִי אָמַרְתִּי ("I said"). Accordingly, the speaker must be God who was speaking in vv. 2-4. The 2nd person plural pronoun אַתֶּם ("you (pl.) are") and the word כֻּלְּכֶם ("all of you (pl.)") indicate that God is still speaking to the "gods"/ judges, to whom he was speaking in vv. 2-4.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: That's how I read the Psalm and it's how the translators of the ESV seem to punctuate it.  Looks good to me.  (It does take some time for a question to be seen.  I just missed it before leaving work last night.  But self-answered questions are just fine on this site.)